# GCP External HTTP(S) Load Balancer statusDetails: "internal_error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

A few days ago we started to receive a huge amount of logs generated by the the external load balancer with `statusDetails: "internal_error"`

This is an example:

```
{
  "insertId": "h7bxsuflmbgkx",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry",
    "remoteIp": "remote_ip_replaced",
    "statusDetails": "internal_error"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "remoteIp": "remote_ip_replaced",
    "latency": "0s"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "http_load_balancer",
    "labels": {
      "backend_service_name": "",
      "url_map_name": "",
      "zone": "global",
      "project_id": "project_id_replaced",
      "target_proxy_name": "",
      "forwarding_rule_name": "rule_name_replaced"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-10-06T19:04:48.807346Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/project_id_replaced/logs/requests",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-10-06T19:04:49.013874339Z"
}
```

The amount of logs that we see is approximately 2 million / hour.

The LB is configured with 4 backend services with serverless NEG to Cloud Run.

No configuration changes in the last 15 days.

The traffic of our application/backend services is the same and it does not seem to be affected by this situation.

Any idea what could be the cause of these error logs?

Comment: What is the status code when you request the external LB?

Comment: @Gabriel Hodoroaga 

This looks like an issue that needs to be brought to Google Cloud's attention. Please submit a report by following this documentation: (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) so it can be reviewed.

Comment: @TimChiang The load balancer is working normal and the requests are routed to the backend services as expected. I receive 200 for valid request or 404 for invalid paths.

Comment: @JamesS This is the ticket link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251722655

Comment: I was able to generate similar log entries by using this command `nmap --script ssl-ccs-injection -p 443 example.com`

Comment: 1/2) It is unlikely that `ssl-ccs-injection` is a problem: 1) This vulnerability was discovered by Google almost 10 years ago and only affects certain versions of OpenSSL and the weakness must exist in both the client and the server. 2) AFAIK Google does not use OpenSSL in the GFE (the load balancer front end). 3) The load balancer errors are probably caused by script kiddies running commands similar to the one you mentioned.

Comment: 2/2) The part that I notice is your comment about 2 million errors being logged per hour. That level approaches a denial of service attack. I recommend that you deploy Cloud Armor. I would also engage support as they can evaluate what level of an attack this is and who/where.

Comment: Since you are running a site about security, you should enable TLS v1.3 and disable anything lower than TLS v1.2. I would also enable http2. Your frontend currently has http2 disabled and rejects TLS v1.3. Your frontend accepts TLS v1.0 which is not good.

Comment: @JohnHanley the load balancer has Cloud Armor enabled already, the backend services are not affected by this.

Comment: That is an important detail that you left out of your question. What do the Cloud Armor logs show?